# How to install Perl on macOS 10.13 High Sierra

Tags: macos, perl, macos-high-sierra

I recently upgraded to macOS 10.13 High Sierra and shortly after encountered a problem attempting to install a more recent version of Perl (5.26.1). The gist of the problem is that the self-tests for `cpan/DB_File` consistently failed on macOS 10.13 High Sierra (home laptop) but succeeded on macOS 10.12 Sierra (work laptop).

Here's the section of the installation log showing the failure:

```
../cpan/Config-Perl-V/t/30_plv5240.t ............................... ok
../cpan/Config-Perl-V/t/31_plv52511.t .............................. ok
../cpan/DB_File/t/db-btree.t ....................................... ok
Use of uninitialized value $value in string eq at t/db-hash.t line 224.
Use of uninitialized value $values[0] in string eq at t/db-hash.t line 224.
Use of uninitialized value $value in lc at t/db-hash.t line 224.
Use of uninitialized value $h{""} in string eq at t/db-hash.t line 243.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==) at t/db-hash.t line 252.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==) at t/db-hash.t line 252.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==) at t/db-hash.t line 252.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==) at t/db-hash.t line 252.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==) at t/db-hash.t line 252.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==) at t/db-hash.t line 252.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==) at t/db-hash.t line 252.
Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==) at t/db-hash.t line 252.
Use of uninitialized value $foo[18] in join or string at t/db-hash.t line 261.
Use of uninitialized value $foo[36] in join or string at t/db-hash.t line 261.
Use of uninitialized value $foo[48] in join or string at t/db-hash.t line 261.
Use of uninitialized value $foo[58] in join or string at t/db-hash.t line 261.
Use of uninitialized value $foo[59] in join or string at t/db-hash.t line 261.
Use of uninitialized value $foo[60] in join or string at t/db-hash.t line 261.
Use of uninitialized value $foo[62] in join or string at t/db-hash.t line 261.
Use of uninitialized value $foo[63] in join or string at t/db-hash.t line 261.
Use of uninitialized value $foo[92] in join or string at t/db-hash.t line 261.
Use of uninitialized value $foo[114] in join or string at t/db-hash.t line 261.
Use of uninitialized value $foo[140] in join or string at t/db-hash.t line 261.
Use of uninitialized value $foo[187] in join or string at t/db-hash.t line 261.
Use of uninitialized value $foo[188] in join or string at t/db-hash.t line 261.
Use of uninitialized value $foo[189] in join or string at t/db-hash.t line 261.
Use of uninitialized value $h{"Fred"} in string eq at t/db-hash.t line 572.
Use of uninitialized value $v in concatenation (.) or string at t/db-hash.t line 748.
../cpan/DB_File/t/db-hash.t ........................................ 
Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
Failed 76/166 subtests
```

I was able to repeat this same failure whether installing using `perlbrew install perl-5.26.1` or simply downloading [the Perl tarfile](http://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.26.1.tar.gz) and installing manually. When I try to debug the test in question `t/db-hash.t`, I can see that the test hash `%h` is created and is being populated in the test file, but when I `print Dumper(\%h)` I see that the hash looks to have the right keys, but *all* of the values are `undef`, rather than the values being assigned in the test script.

These `undef` values are causing the test failure. Oddly, the undefined values show up when I print the whole hash or try to make an array of the hash values. If I ask for a specific hash key's value, e.g. `my $value = $h{key}`, the value prints fine.

Questions:

- How to fix this so that I can install a new Perl on macOS 10.13?
- What broke? This used to work on macOS 10.12.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Here's what worked:

1. Install Berkeley DB. I use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh), but you can get the source files at the [Oracle site](https://www.oracle.com/database/berkeley-db/db.html).

   ```
   brew install berkeley-db
   ```
2. Install Perl. I use [Perlbrew](https://perlbrew.pl), but you can get the source files at the [Perl site](http://www.perl.org/get.html).

   ```
   perlbrew install perl-5.26.1
   ```

---

#### A Partial Explanation

Looking back through the failed installation log, there is a warning near the `DB_File` sections that gives a clue:

```
...
./miniperl -Ilib make_ext.pl lib/auto/DB_File/DB_File.bundle  MAKE="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make" LIBPERL_A=libperl.a LINKTYPE=dynamic
Parsing config.in...
Looks Good.
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -ldb
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for DB_File
...
```

No `db` library found, *mostly* harmless.

According to the docs for the [`DB_File` module](http://perldoc.perl.org/DB_File.html), it is...

> ...  a module which allows Perl programs to make use of the facilities provided by Berkeley DB...

After installing `berkeley-db`, the same section of the Perl installation log no longer shows the same warning:

```
...
./miniperl -Ilib make_ext.pl lib/auto/DB_File/DB_File.bundle  MAKE="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make" LIBPERL_A=libperl.a LINKTYPE=dynamic
Parsing config.in...
Looks Good.
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for DB_File
...
```

And further along the process, the previously failed tests pass, allowing installation to complete successfully:

```
...
../cpan/DB_File/t/db-btree.t ....................................... ok
../cpan/DB_File/t/db-hash.t ........................................ ok
../cpan/DB_File/t/db-recno.t ....................................... ok
...
```

I haven't been able to find any documentation online about why Berkeley DB appears to be missing from macOS 10.13 High Sierra, and whether that was a change from previous macOS versions, as it seems.

Many thanks to Tim D for helping me troubleshoot.

Comment: It's probably worth reporting this on rt.perl.org. That 'mostly harmless' needs to be changed when libdb isn't installed!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @RickMeasham. I'll do that.

Comment: Bug report filed using `perlbug`. FYI @RickMeasham.

Answer (score 2):

To install perl itself (which contains the DB_File module), or to install the DB_File module from CPAN, the solution is the same:  edit its `config.in` to point to the proper location of berkeley-db.

For example, I have installed the db48 package via macports with `sudo port install db48`.  In the perl download itself, I navigate to cpan/DB_File and edit its `config.in`, changing the existing INCLUDE and LIB assignments thusly:

```
INCLUDE    = /opt/local/include/db48
LIB        = /opt/local/lib/db48
```

I can then resume the perl build process and DB_File can compile.

References:

[Perl RT#133280](https://rt.perl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=133280)
[CPAN RT#125238](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=125238)

Comment: While I think this is useful information in general, it wouldn't have solved my problem. The problem was that the `berkeley-db` library was missing entirely from the system, not that it couldn't be found during Perl install configuration.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear: part of the solution is to install berkeley-db (e.g. via macports or homebrew), and then tell perl's DB_File where to find it, as its `config.in` is pointing to the incorrect location.